# ldap last login command

Tags: ldap, ldapconnection

I have LDAP server (on solaris) and UNIX application server that connected to it.
I would like to find out, how to check when the first and last time that the users were login to the UNIX application server.
I prefer solution from ldap side and not from the unix server (cause we reset the unix server often).

Thanks!

Asaf.

Comment: This is not enough information. WHich LDAP directory server product is deployed on Solaris?

Comment: Got handle it...
the access file containes all the entries on ldap users. /var/ds/logs/access

Thanks 
Asaf